# Django: Page doesn't load images

Tags: python, django, web

I am working on a Django project for a company. This project worked very well before today.

Today I found a page can not show images (and their corrsponding links). I checked source code of THAT PAGE, I found there are images and links, I just can not find them on the page.

I checked the auth of the server and I am sure I can write things to the database. In fact, I think it is not database mistake because I can find what I want in the page source code, I just can not find them on the page.

Oh my Gosh, I am going to be crazy...

Has anyone suffered similar problem? What kind of problem could it be?

Please help me! Thank you very much!

PS: I can not provide any source code of the project because some business limit...I am really sorry...

Comment: what happens when you copy n paste the image urls on to the browser's address bar? Are the images present in the server - did you/someone accidentally delete/rename/move them?

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring the site_media directory. If you're images are being served up as static content it could be related to the permissions of that folder on local disk or based on the settings.

Within your urls you may have something similar to:

```
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),
```

OR it may reference the path in the settings file something similar to:

```
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = '/path/to/media'
```

If the link looks correct for the image, but the side is not rendering the image even directly  your issue will be somewhere in these areas.

For more information check the django docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid question...I wasted ur guys time. I have solved it...Thank you very much!